# Not able to connect to RabbitMq server using a particular user

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I tried to connect to a particular RabbitMq machine using following code using MassTransit

```
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
      {
        x.UseRabbitMq();
        x.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://admin:admin@<IP Address>/somequeue");

        moreInitialization(x);
      });
```

I have create a user as admin in vhost "\" with administrator privileges.

```
cmd:> rabbitmqctl list_permissions
Listing permissions in vhost "/" ...
admin   .*      .*      .*
```

I have removed the "guest" user. Even though I user the below code, I can see in rabbitmq log as below

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Jun-2015::12:19:22 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.391.0> (192.168.6.1:7000 -> 192.168.6.131:5672):
{handshake_error,starting,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials",
                             'connection.start_ok'}}
```

At application side I am getting the below error

```
Exception:Thrown: "ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile." (RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AuthenticationFailureException)
A RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AuthenticationFailureException was thrown: "ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile."
```

Do I need to change any configuration in rabbitmq.config file? I am using RabbitMq Server version 3.5.3

Thanks for helping

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? Maybe we had a similar issue. A particular user wouldn't allow the script to log in. We double-checked the credentials and it worked fine on a separate system with the same script and user id. Even setting the password again did not help. Only deleting and newly creating the user helped. Like something went wrong when originally creating the user, but nothing indicated a problem then.

Answer (score 1):

To specify credentials, you need to configure the host explicitly. The @ syntax is no longer supported, due to leakage of security credentials.

For example:

```cs
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{
    sbc.UseRabbitMq(r => r.ConfigureHost(new Uri("rabbitmq://actual-server-name/queue-name"), h =>
    {
        h.SetUsername("username");
        h.SetPassword("password");
    }));
    sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://actual-server-name/queue-name");
});
```